# Wrap all items when any item does not fit using CSS and no width media query?

Tags: css

Is it possible to wrap all items if any of the items does not fit?

In the following example the last item wraps when I make the view port 800px. I would like the second item to wrap as well. I am not sure if I am using the correct terminology for what I am trying to describe.

I have considered using a width media query, but that would not help as I don't know the width of the text.

```
<div class='flex-container'>
  <div class='flex-item'>Hi there.</div>
  <div class='flex-item'>Mr Bond.</div>
  <div class='flex-item'>How are you?</div>
</div>  

.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Limitations:
* Am looking for a pure CSS solution, no JS

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MVqRKa

Comment: No, not withuot a media query...

Comment: Thanks both. Then I know. @VXp that is a good idea, but the content will be dynamically loaded so I can't use that method.

Comment: Like said, not possible without JS, assumed that you want them to stack vertically when the "break" happens on the last one.